# Sharepoint 2013 Parent document library on a subsite

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am new to share point and still learning all the best practices, but I have a parent site called "Clients"  and a sub site for the each of the clients i.e. Walmart, Kmart, Target.  Is it a best practice to have a unique document library for each of the sub sites and the parent site.  Or to use just one library for all of them.  And if I were to use just one how would I set that up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Sites and Pages are not the same!!!**

I wish that was more clear.  In this case I want a SITE with the customers.  Then each customer will have its own page.  This way I can use the same apps across all the customers.  I will probably need to learn how to create a customer template next.

Answer (score 0):

to start with you need to answer few questions first, and these questions will help you to decide on an approach.

- Do you have unique documents per client
- will you control access to your users, that is each subsite will have unique permission, users for one client say for instance walmart should not access documents of Kmart
- what would be tentative size of each documents and how much will that grow over the year

above are few question which will help you to get started, being said that, I will start creating a site and if the look and feel are the same for my other clients with little changes, then save the site as template. 
This template will be my base for other client subsites/ sites.

will also create a global document library, which will store relavant documents which can be sharable across subsites

If required, each client will have their own subsites and own libraries for maintainabilty. this will also help to move subsite to its own site collection if there is hugh growth in data for a particular client.

You can also plan to use search, and webparts like content search query webpart to mashup data from subsites. 
Another area to explore is metadata and Information architecture.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask "Is it best practices" for the multiple Libraries or a single Library. From what you have described and Ramakrishnaraja was trying to say, you need to figure out what would work best for the situation. I don't know if you mean to have a different group called "customers" or if that is the same as "Clients" I'm going to respond assuming you mean both parties are the same.

Ramakrishnaraja points out that you have one central log on page "Clients- 'Main'" which leads to the other pages. If you want to the users to be divided into groups that have access only to the documents within their repective page then you should create multiple Document libraries. If you want the users to have access between the sub pages and use/edit files between the sites then best practices would be to have one Library for the Site.

I hope this helps you. Ramakrishnaraja makes a lot of good points and approaches it from a design overview rather than a specific response to your situation so try to use his post from that perspective.